# Show that the finite set $S=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis for vector space $V$ iff as follows.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an arbitrary vector space over $\Bbb F$.
Show that the finite set $S=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ iff $V=\langle v_1 \rangle \oplus \langle v_2 \rangle \oplus \ldots \langle v_n \rangle$.

**Attempt:**
for right direction, assume that $S$ is a basis of $V$. To show: $V = \langle v_1 \rangle \oplus \langle v_2 \rangle \oplus \ldots \langle v_n \rangle$.
Since $S$ is a basis of $V$, then for all $v \in V$, we have $v = c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + \ldots + c_nv_n$ for all $c_i \in \Bbb F$.
Thus, $v \in \langle v_1 \rangle + \langle v_2 \rangle + \ldots + \langle v_n \rangle$. Also, the equation $0=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+ \ldots + c_nv_n$ is only satisfied by $c_i = 0$ for all $c_i \in \Bbb F$. Hence, $\langle v_1 \rangle \cap \langle v_2 \rangle \cap \ldots \cap \langle v_n \rangle = \{0\}$. Therefore, $V = \langle v_1 \rangle \oplus \langle v_2 \rangle \oplus \ldots \langle v_n \rangle$.

for the converse, assume that $V$ is a direct sum of all $\langle v_i \rangle$ for $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. To show: the set $S:= \{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$. By hypothesis, $V = \langle v_1 \rangle + \langle v_2 \rangle + \ldots \langle v_n \rangle = c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + \ldots + c_nv_n$. Hence, span$S= V$.
I got stucked here.

Anyway, am the above correct ?

Comment: Your solution is all correct. You've essentially got the converse. Maybe try using the uniqueness characterization of $\oplus$.

Comment: @DanielApsley for the right directio is true ?

Comment: Yes. I think that was all good.

Comment: For the converse, dimension is additive over direct sums, i.e., $\dim V = n.$